# How to pad out an image to create a banner effect in HTML

Tags: html

I have a small image with a coloured background that I want to place at the top of an HTML page to the right, and have a band of the same background colour fill the space to the left, so that it just looks like a banner. I then want the rest of the page (text) to continue below the banner, not wrap around the image. 
I would prefer to use an inline style rather than CSS, but either is fine.

If I could wave a magic wand over the HTML syntax, I would have something like:

```
<body>
<image-as-banner src='mylogo.jpg' align='right' background-color='black'>
<p>And my normal text starts here underneath the banner</p>
</body>
```

That is to say... if I could slip in a single line of HTML to achieve this, I'd like to know what it is. It needs to specify the image, the fact that it wants to be aligned to the right, banner style, and that the colour to pad out the remaining space is black. Of course, there is no `image-as-banner` tag in HTML.

Comment: a) paste some code b) what's do you call the difference between an inline style and CSS

Comment: A) Use some imagination :-) src="logo.jpg" is the only concrete element of what I have. It's the HTML context around it I'm interested in. B) As I understand it, style="..." is a global HTML attribute that allows style elements to be specified for any tag. This is "inline".

Comment: cool, a) It's just easier for us to comment on b) just so you know this attribute is still CSS, it is usually best to separate the styles from the markup, makes it easier to update later.

Comment: Hey - please don't edit my question - it was fine as it was. If I wanted to write <img class="img-banner"..> I would have written that. Your edit prejudices the answers. Using a class attribute is one possible answer. I wrote <img-banner ...> for a reason, and indicated that there was no img-banner tag in HTML. As before, please use some imagination :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a div container with background image and color attributes like so:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#banner{
 background-image:url(images/banner.jpg);
 background-color: #$$$$$$;
 background-position: right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: $px;
 height: $px;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: OK - I am trying to inline this using <div style="..."> and including the style elements you have listed. Should it be possible? I have my reasons... :-) So far, my image always gets clipped to the height of the line created by the &nbsp;, so if I zoom the text in or out, the image height changes. Hmmm....

Comment: specify the div's height attribute to that of or greater than the image's height.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..?

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#container{width:100%;margin:0 auto;height:100%;background-color:grey;}
#banner{width:100%;height:100px;background-color:red;}
img{float:right;height:100px;}
#text{}
</style>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
    <div id='banner'><img src='http://darmano.typepad.com/logic_emotion/images/red.jpg'>
    </div>
    <div id='text'>
    <h3>Put your text here..</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: There are three opening <div> tags, and only two closing ones - please edit to clarify. Also... you have a fixed 800pix width. What if my browser width is 320pix, or 1680pix?

Comment: @omatai The banner div is closed on the same line.

Comment: Oops - didn't see that, sorry :-)

Comment: you could only see the third closing `<div>` when you scrolled to the right, i put an extra enter there for clarity. I would suggest you put the width on 100% then so it automatically adjusts to the size of your screen.

Comment: Thanks - I have got this to work in my context. Is there any purpose to the container? Is it essential? It would be good if I could reduce this to a few lines of code that could be slipped into the normal flow of the text.

Comment: I don't think the container is essential. You could try removing it, it comes in handy when setting the margin to 0 auto, you only have to do this once then.

Answer (score 0):

To the example you've pasted above, something like this might do the trick

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
.img-banner {
    background-color: black;
    align: right;
    /* etc etc etc */
}
</style>

<div class="img-banner">
    <img src='mylogo.jpg' alt=''>
</div>

<p>And my normal text starts here underneath the banner</p>

</body>
</html>
```